# Haskell can't zip strings then combine with list comprehension

Tags: haskell

```
combineIndex :: String -> String -> [Char]
combineIndex pair1 pair2 = [a ++ b | (a, b) <- zip pair1 pair2]
```

`combineIndex "AB" "CD"` should return `["AC", "BD"]` but I just keep getting type errors.

Comment: what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: `Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[a0]’`  `In the expression: a ++ b`, and `Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’ with actual type ‘Char’` `In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘b’`

Comment: But here in your "wanted result", you actually show a list of *2-tuples*, not a string (like you specified earlier in the signature.

Comment: `++` takes lists, not `Char`s, as arguments. `a` and `b` are `Char` values.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry, fixed it.

Comment: Can't help bikeshedding: `combineIndex p1 p2 = transpose [p1, p2]` (though this behaves slightly differently than `zip` when the arguments have different lengths).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> combineIndex `"AB" "CD"` should return `["AC", "BD"]` but I just keep getting type errors.

Well let us first take a look at the signature of your function:

```
combineIndex :: String -> String -> [Char]
combineIndex pair1 pair2 = [a ++ b | (a, b) <- zip pair1 pair2]
```

As result type, you specify a `[Char]`, so a list of `Char`s (which is in fact a `String`). But in your result, you want a *list of `String`*, so the output type should be a `[String]`. So let us first fix the signature:

```
combineIndex :: String -> String -> [String]
combineIndex pair1 pair2 = [a ++ b | (a, b) <- zip pair1 pair2]
```

Now in order to create such strings, we might first analyze the types of the variables involved. [**`zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip), will return a list of 2-tuples `[(Char, Char)]`. So that means that the `a` and `b` in the list comprehension are both `Char`s. We can convert these chars into a `String` by constructing a list of two elements `[a,b]`. So we can fix the function with:

```
combineIndex :: String -> String -> [String]
combineIndex pair1 pair2 = [ [a, b] | (a, b) <- zip pair1 pair2]
```

The [**`(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) function will not work here, since it requires two lists (with the *same* type of elements), and concatenates these lists together. But a `Char` is not a list, a `String` is (since `type String = [Char]`). We could have writteh `[a] ++ [b]` instead of `[a, b]`, but this will make it only more *noisy* and less efficient.

Note that we can *generalize* the function further to:

```
combineIndex :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
combineIndex pair1 pair2 = [ [a, b] | (a, b) <- zip pair1 pair2]
```

So now it will work with any two lists that have the same type of objects. For example if we call this with numbers, we get:

```
Prelude> combineIndex [1,4,2,5] [1,3,0,2]
[[1,1],[4,3],[2,0],[5,2]]
```

Answer (score 5):

`zip` returns tuples of *`Char`* values, not `String` values, so you can't use `++` on `a` and `b`. You just want an ordinary list.

```
combineIndex p1 p2 = [[a,b] | (a, b) <- zip p1 p2]
```